# Prove that X has at most three elements.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let be $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that a euclidean metric induces in $X$ a metric zero-one. Prove that $X$ has at most three elements

I do not know how to start... What's mean "such that a euclidean metric induces in X a metric zero-one"??

Comment: I don't know what it means. Perhaps you should look it up in your book/ask the lecture note provider/ask your teacher/ask whomever gave you this problem

Comment: The metric induced on a subspace is simply the metric of the containing space evaluated at the (pairs of) points of the subspace -- so this is just a fancy way of saying that the distances are measured in $X$ just as they're measured in all of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: It means if you view $X$ as a metric space, equipped with the Euclidean metric $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then for all $p \in X, q \in X$, $d(p, q) = 0$ or $d(p, q) = 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: "induces in $X$ a metric zero-one" is incomprehensible to me as a native English speaker. You are right that it must mean something like what you suggest in this context, but please don't promulgate new interpretations of nonsensical English.

Comment: To elaborate, how large can such a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be??

Comment: @RobArthan Good point, in fact myself found such statement weird too.

Comment: @RobArthan:  I see nothing in Zhanxiong's Comment that "promulgates nonsensical English."  The Comment is clear and helpful.

Comment: It's in the question, not the comment.

Comment: @hardmath: what I am complaining about is promulgating pointless new terminology. So you are likely right: what I am objecting to is the two answers that "guess" or "expect" what is meant  rather than giving any real help on the terminology at issue.

Comment: It seems a widely used phrase (for the discrete metric) is the "zero-one metric", so if the word order were changed, I'd not find the phrase weird.

Comment: metric zero-one, is a discrete metric, and You not have to be a genius to understand this, thanks for your answers

Comment: Responding to the (correct) observation that the question is not in English with "you not have to be a genius" earns a -1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I expect this means is that $$d(x,y)=\cases{0 & \text{ if $x=y$}\\ 1 & \text{ if $x\neq y$}.}$$

To prove this statement, assume that $x\in\mathbb R^2$ is one of the points in $X$. All of the other points must lie on a circle of radius $1$ centered at $x$. Suppose that $y$ is on the circle and $y\in X$. Then if $z\in X$, $z$ must lie on both the circle of radius $1$ centered at $x$ and the circle of radius $1$ centered at $y$. These circles have only two intersection points. If $z$ is one of these points, then the other is at a distance greater than $1$ from $z$. Thus, no other points besides $x,y,$ and $z$ can be in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess the meaning is that the distance between any two points of $X$ is either $0$ or $1$.